# getView não está sendo chamado mas getCount tem itens no ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, volley

Estou tendo um problema com um ListView que não está carregando os valores. Essa é a minha situação:

Tenho uma aplicação que em determinado momento abre um TabBar com 2 Fragments e dentro de um destes Fragments eu tenho uma ListView que estou tentando popular através de um request POST com o Volley.

Estou trazendo os valores corretamente pelo webservice eele trás resultados (o getCount() no Adapter tem valores), mas ele não está entrando no getView() então acredito que deva ser por isso que ele não está exibindo nada no ListView.

**Adapter:**

```
 public class LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> mDataSource;

    public LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter(Context context, List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> items)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        try
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View sView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lancarvenda_carrinho_list_view_item, parent, false);

            PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno sItem = (PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno) getItem(position);

            TextView descricao = (TextView)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txtdescricao);
            descricao.setText(sItem.getDescricao());

            TextView preco = (TextView)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txvpreco);
            preco.setText(String.valueOf(sItem.getPreco()));

            EditText quantidade = (EditText)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_etquantidade);
            quantidade.setText("1");

            return sView;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> getItemList()
    {
        return mDataSource;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> itemList)
    {
        this.mDataSource = itemList;
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
 public class LancarVendaCarrinhoFragment extends Fragment 
 {
    private ListView fCarrinhoResultado;
    List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> sCarrinhoAuxiliar;
    LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter sAdaptador;

    private PesquisarProdutoRequest sCorpoBusca = new PesquisarProdutoRequest();

    public LancarVendaCarrinhoFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater sInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View sView = sInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, null);

        fCarrinhoResultado = (ListView) sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_lvwresultado);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Time sData = new Time();
        sData.setToNow();

        sCorpoBusca = new PesquisarProdutoRequest();
        sCorpoBusca.setIdioma("pt-BR");
        sCorpoBusca.setUsaGrade(Variaveis.UsaGrade);
        sCorpoBusca.setFilial(Variaveis.Filial);
        sCorpoBusca.setUFFilial(Variaveis.UFFilial);
        sCorpoBusca.setTipoSistema(Variaveis.TipoSistema);
        sCorpoBusca.setNumeroCaixa(Variaveis.NumeroCaixa);
        sCorpoBusca.setRede(Variaveis.Rede);
        sCorpoBusca.setTabelaTributo((byte) 0);
        sCorpoBusca.setCodigoProduto("0030900939");

        PesquisarProduto();


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, container, false);
    }


    private void PesquisarProduto() {
        RequestQueue sQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        String sEnderecoBase = "http://www.minha-url";

        sCarrinhoAuxiliar = new ArrayList<>();

        StringRequest sRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, sEnderecoBase, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                PesquisarProdutoResponse sResultado = new Gson().fromJson((String) response, PesquisarProdutoResponse.class);
                if (sResultado.getCodigoRetorno() == 0) {
                    Variaveis.Carrinho.add(sResultado);

                    try {

                        sCarrinhoAuxiliar.clear();

                        for (int i = 0; i < Variaveis.Carrinho.size(); i++) {
                            PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno sItem = Variaveis.Carrinho.get(i).getDadosProduto();
                            sCarrinhoAuxiliar.add(sItem);
                            Variaveis.CarrinhoAuxiliar.add(sItem);
                        }

                        sAdaptador = new LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter(getActivity(), sCarrinhoAuxiliar);
                        sAdaptador.setItemList(sCarrinhoAuxiliar);
                        fCarrinhoResultado.setAdapter(sAdaptador);

                        sAdaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                byte[] sBytesResposta = error.networkResponse.data;
                String sTexto = new String(sBytesResposta);
                Mensagem.ExibirAlert(getActivity(), String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> sHeaders = new HashMap<>();
                sHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + Variaveis.ApiToken);
                return sHeaders;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return new Gson().toJson(sCorpoBusca).getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };

        sQueue.add(sRequest);
    }
}
```

**Layout do Fragment**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lancarvenda_carrinho_lvwresultado"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout da célula:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/lancarvenda_carrinho_item_imvFoto"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo_foto2"
        app:border_color="#898989"
        app:border_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txtdescricao"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Relogio Mormaii 2730"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txvpreco"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="R$ 399,89"
                    android:textColor="#1ba39c"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lancarvenda_carrinho_item_etquantidade"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="#9a9b9c"
                    android:hint="0"
                    android:textColor="#2a2d2e"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Eu fiz um teste populando uma variável pública em uma outra página e depois populei um ListView qualquer em outra Activity e funcionou, ele passa pelo getView() e mostra o ListView corretamente mas não no Fragment sendo populado no próprio Fragment.

Alguma sugestão? Estou há dias pesquisando por uma solução e nada..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está a popular uma instância de ListView que não é aquela que é apresentada no *fragment*.

A ListView que é apresentada no *fragment* está no *layout* que é criado no `onCreateView()`, através de `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, container, false)`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Time sData = new Time();
    sData.setToNow();

    sCorpoBusca = new PesquisarProdutoRequest();
    .....
    .....
    sCorpoBusca.setCodigoProduto("0030900939");

    PesquisarProduto();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, container, false);
}
```

A ListView a que foi atribuída o adapter foi criada no `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater sInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View sView = sInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, null);

    fCarrinhoResultado = (ListView) sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_lvwresultado);
}
```

Obtenha a referência à ListView no `onCreateView()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View sView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lancarvenda_carrinho, container, false);

    fCarrinhoResultado = (ListView) sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_lvwresultado);

    Time sData = new Time();
    sData.setToNow();

    sCorpoBusca = new PesquisarProdutoRequest();
    .....
    .....
    sCorpoBusca.setCodigoProduto("0030900939");

    PesquisarProduto();

    return view;
}
```

Elimine o método `onCreate()`.

Comment: Muito obrigada, muito obrigada mesmo! funcionou perfeitamente!